# Footer is not being shown properly on different device heights

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

I am having a problem with my footer. I have a page with some content and on some devices (like mobile - in zoomed out view), my page content does not fill parent device height while on some devices, it does.
The footer is creating a problem with these different heights. When the content doesn't fill the parent device height, the footer is shown correctly at the bottom of the page but when the content fills the parent device height and overflows, the footer is shown over the content.

Footer with content not filling Parent height (shows correctly)

[image: Footer with content not filling Parent height(showing correctly)]

Footer with overflown content (doesn't show correctly)

[image]

Picture quality is not that clear but the issue is clearly visible.

This is the CSS code I have been using till now.

```
#footer{
     display:block;
     margin-right:auto;
     margin-left:auto;
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0;
     height:100px;
     width: 60%;
     text-align:center;
     color:green;
     font-size:18px;
     font-family:Times;
 }
```

How can this be fixed? I want to show the footer at the end of the page when content is overflown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your #main element right before the footer (assuming you are using `id="main"` for the item with the green border, do the following:

```
#main {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

EDIT:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="main"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my comment.  Can you mimic that HTML structure (see the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/5LSQ4/)

Comment: It worked but its giving extra empty space between content and footer when content is overflown

Comment: i think now the footer is dependent on the margin of main element. It will not show the footer correctly in less content

Answer (score 0):

whenever you position something absolute you take it outside of the DOM, meaning in this case it sits bottom 0 (based on your css) to the the nearest relatively positioned element.  I put the footer html after your wrap or content block and just have it centered by saying

```
margin 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the footer to be absolutely positioned, you could always add a margin-bottom or padding-bottom to the body element. Just make it the 100px of your absolutely positioned element and it should force the content above your positioned element.

Alternatively, you could just set the footer to be positioned static, but you'll lose the ability for the footer to be at the bottom of the screen when your content is too short.